# Arbitrary 'columns' from HashMap in hibernate query

Tags: java, hibernate, jsf, el

Suppose I have an entity User

```
public class User {
    private String username;
    private String password;

    private Map<String, Object> settings = new HashMap<String, Object>();

    //Getters & setters
}
```

Is there any way that I can use the key of the settings map in a query?
Eg:

```
Criterion crit = mySession.createCriterion(User.class);
crit.add(Restrictions.eq("settings.blah", 1234L));
List<User> results = crit.list();
```

Or access the map values via EL?
Eg:

```
<h:dataTable value="#{myBean.users}" var="user">
    <h:column>
        <h:outputText value="#{user.blah}"/>
    </h:column>
</h:dataTable>
```

I can partially do this with a simple @OneToMany mapping, but that required my query to use both key and value, and the properties are not accessible through EL.

Is something like this possible? How would I map it with annotations?

Thanks

EDIT:
Essentially, what I am after is a 'vertical table' implementation so that I can have arbitrary fields, and still be able to use the Entity as a mapped Class. I do not know if this is even possible with hibernate.

Answer (score 1):

I never user Object as a value of the map, you can use String with this mapping:

```
@Entity
public class User {

private int _id;
private Map<String, String> _settings;

public User() {

}

@Id
@GeneratedValue
public int getId() {
    return _id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    _id = id;
}

@ElementCollection
@MapKeyColumn(name = "SETTINGS_KEY")
@CollectionTable(name = "USER_SETTINGS", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"))
@Column(name = "SETTING")
public Map<String, String> getSettings() {
    return _settings;
}

public void setSettings(Map<String, String> settings) {
    _settings = settings;
}

}
```

If you need to use different type of columns then you must use a interface as value of the map like this:

```
@Entity
public class TestSettings {

    private int _id;
    private Map<String, SettingValue<?>> _settings;

    public TestSettings() {

    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    public int getId() {
        return _id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        _id = id;
    }

    @OneToMany
    @MapKeyColumn(name = "SETTINGS_KEY")
    @CollectionTable(name = "USER_SETTINGS", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"))
    @Column(name = "SETTING")
    public Map<String, SettingValue<?>> getSettings() {
        return _settings;
    }

    public void setSettings(Map<String, SettingValue<?>> settings) {
        _settings = settings;
    }

}
```

The SettingValue abstract class:

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.JOINED)
public abstract class SettingValue<V> implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 3355627640146408150L;

    private Integer _id;

    public SettingValue() {
        super();
    }

    @Id @GeneratedValue
    public Integer getId() {
        return _id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        _id = id;
    }

    @Transient
    public abstract V getValue();

    public abstract void setValue(V value);

}
```

The settingValue String implementation:

```
@Entity
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="settingvalue_id", referencedColumnName="id")
public class TextSettingValue extends SettingValue<String> implements Serializable {

    private String _value;

    public TextSettingValue() {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    public void setValue(String value) {
        _value = value;
    }

    @Override
    public String getValue() {
        return _value;
    }

}
```

You have to create a SettingValue implementation for each type you want to support, in this way you get a table for each type with a column to hold your value.